# Opening Dialog drawer half way

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to trigger a dialog box to open when a button is clicked so that it takes up half the height of the blue area as shown in the picture below, while the remaining top half will have the backdrop. Currently i'm unable to force the dialog box to open up in the specific area (blue area), instead it takes up the fullscreen and i'm not sure how to change that. I've added a sample code in codesanbox to show what I have done to try to do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rryul

[image: This is an image showing what I would like to achieve]

This is an image showing what I would like to achieve

```
export default function CenteredGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Paper style={{ height: 500, background: "blue" }}>
            <div>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                color="white"
                onClick={handleClickOpen}
              >
                Open full-screen dialog
              </Button>
              <Dialog
                fullScreen
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                TransitionComponent={Transition}
              >
                <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
                  <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                      edge="start"
                      color="inherit"
                      onClick={handleClose}
                      aria-label="close"
                    >
                      <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                      Sound
                    </Typography>
                    <Button autoFocus color="inherit" onClick={handleClose}>
                      save
                    </Button>
                  </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <List>
                  <ListItem button>
                    <ListItemText
                      primary="Phone ringtone"
                      secondary="Titania"
                    />
                  </ListItem>
                  <Divider />
                  <ListItem button>
                    <ListItemText
                      primary="Default notification ringtone"
                      secondary="Tethys"
                    />
                  </ListItem>
                </List>
              </Dialog>
            </div>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Paper style={{ height: 500, background: "purple" }} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If anything is unclear, just let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material ui `Dialog` is rendered as [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). As per [doc](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#inheritance), `Modal` component's props are also available to `Dialog`.

So you can use the `Modal`'s [container](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props) prop in `Dialog` and provide a `target` which indicates where to display the portal.

> The container will have the portal children appended to it.
> By default, it uses the body of the top-level document object,

[Working demo (codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-dialog-open-styling-ms4f0?file=/demo.js)

**dialog style**

```js
dialog: {
    background: "orange",
    position: "relative !important",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    padding: "100px 0px 0px 0px", //change this based on your needs
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"
  }
```

**dialog jsx**

```js
...
      const container = React.useRef(null);
...
...
          <Dialog
                container={container.current}//<---here
                fullScreen
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                TransitionComponent={Transition}
                className={classes.dialog}
              >
...
```

Comment: The problem with the example is that the backdrop (The dark, greyed out area) is covering the whole screen not just the remaining blue area that's not covered by the dialog, I wanted to find a way to make it so that only the blue area has the black drop when button is clicked and the rest of the areas including the purple area should not have a backdrop, hope it makes sense, if not then let me know @gdh